# Manually update the mtime of a file in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Is it possible to manually alter the date of a file on a UNIX system (to a previous date)?

If so, how would I tackle this problem?

How would I be able to do the same thing on multiple files at the same time?

Comment: You can use `touch file` to make it have the current date.

Comment: Updated the question. I'm only looking at making the files look older than they are.

Comment: You can fake it changing your datetime `sudo date -s "sometime in the past"`, then `touch` it and go back to current date.

Comment: Forget my explanation, @BeniBela answer solves this easier. Did not know about `-d` in touch.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use touch. E.g::

```
touch -d '2007-01-31 8:46:26' file
```

Or often easier, if you have a file2 which has already the mtime, you can copy the time with -r:

```
touch -r file2 file
```

There is also the -t option with its strange format:

```
touch -t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] file
```

Comment: +1 since this is a good solution for a Linux box. But it looks like `-d` is not a valid option on an OS X machine.

Comment: Added an older option which also seems to exist on [mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/touch.1.html)

Comment: `-t` is POSIX so it's a good bet to be supported on most current unices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 touch -m -d '1 Jan 2006 12:34' test.txt
```

-m Change only the modification time
-d (--date=STRING) with the date you want to put in

extracted from the manual:

```
DATE STRING
       The  --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A
       date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty  string  indicates
       the beginning of the day.  The date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.
```

for more info you can read the touch manual, running man touch.

i hope that helps.